# Early Disposable of an IAsyncEnumerable Takes Forever

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have a query I am running against my database using EF Core 3.1 with Postgresql that can sometimes return a large result set depending on the parameters requested. I am using Async Enumerable to stream the results, which can sometimes take over a minute to complete:

```
try
{
    IAsyncEnumerable<Entity> ae = ctxt.Entity.Where(e => e.Value > 5).AsAsyncEnumerable();

    await foreach(Entity e in ae.ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        //Do some work on each one here that could potentially throw an exception
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //This code can take over a minute after the exception is thrown to begin executing
}
```

I then got rid of the `await foreach` loop to get a better idea what was happening:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<Entity> ae = ctxt.Entity.Where(e => e.Value > 5).AsAsyncEnumerable();
var enumerator = ae.GetAsyncEnumerator();
await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
Console.WriteLline("Done Disposing");
```

And found that the `DisposeAsync` call was where the time was being spent. I went back to the `await foreach` and was able to confirm that using `break` inside the loop exhibited the same behavior.

Next, I tried creating a non-ef `IAsyncEnumerable` to see if this behavior was isolated to Entity Frameowork or not.

```cs
private async IAsyncEnumerable<int> IntEnumerator()
{
    await Task.Delay(0).ConfigureAwait(false);

    for(int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
      yield return i;
    }
}
```

Using this code, the Dispose was instant.

```
IAsyncEnumerable<int> ae = IntEnumerator();
var enumerator = ae.GetAsyncEnumerator();
await enumerator.MoveNextAsync();
await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
Console.WriteLline("Done Disposing");
```

This leads me to believe the issue is specific to EF core, but I am not sure if it is a bug in their implementation, or I am doing something wrong. Has anyone else seen something like this and found a solution?

I wanted to check here before opening an issue on the EF github page.

Comment: All EF Core does on `DisposeAsync` is to `Close` + `DisposeAsync` the underlying `DbDataReader` and then `CloseAsync` the underlying `DbConnection`. So most likely this could be an issue with the underlying PostgreSQL ADO.NET provider than EF Core You can turn on EF Core logging (with `LogLevel.Debug`) and see what is the slow operation.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah, I have been doing a bit more digging, and found this: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/dev/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlDataReader.cs#L773. Which gets called on dispose. It looks to me like it is iterating over the remaining entities instead of just terminating early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is actually an issue with postgresql. [See the issue I opened on the Npgsql github page](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2870). According to the maintainer, it is not resolvable.